# How to handle duplicate parameters in a POST request in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey 2.22.1 to implement a REST API.

I would like to know how to handle duplicate parameters in a POST request.

This is my resource class:

```
public class MyResource
{
    @NotNull(message = "Missing parameter 'param1'")
    @FormParam("param1")
    private String m_param1;

    @NotNull(message = "Missing parameter 'param2'")
    @FormParam("param2")
    private String m_param2;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response test(String body)
    {
        // at this point...
        // the value of `body` is the full request body
        // the value of `m_param1` is the 1st value of param1 in the request body
        // the value of `m_param2` is the value of param2 in the request body
        ...
    }
}
```

E.g. if I send a POST request with the following body:

`param1=00000001&param2=00000002&param1=00000003`

then the value of `m_param1` is `00000001`.

Can the Jersey framework detect the presence of a duplicate parameter in the request body? Or do I need add code to parse the request body to look for duplicates?

Comment: `@FormParam("param1") List<Sting> param1s`. Jersey does all the work

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Thanks. Just tried your suggestion but it's not feasible. I would have to change the types of all the form params to `List<String>`. The example shows a simplified version of what I have. In reality, there are a lot more parameters than that and I want to be able to reject all duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) to check the parameters to make sure there are no duplicates. If there are, just send a 400 status.

```
public class DuplicateFormParamsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        ContainerRequest cr = (ContainerRequest) requestContext;
        cr.bufferEntity();
        Form form = cr.readEntity(Form.class);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> asMap = form.asMap();
        for (String key: asMap.keySet()) {
            if (asMap.get(key).size() > 1) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Duplicate param: " + key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are reading the request entity, but first buffering it, so that Jersey can re-read it.

Here is a complete example, using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

/**
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class DuplicateFormParamsTest extends JerseyTest {
    
    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        
        @POST
        @NoDuplicateParams
        @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        public String post(@FormParam("param") String param) {
            return param;
        }
    }
    
    @NoDuplicateParams
    public static class DuplicateFormParamsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            ContainerRequest cr = (ContainerRequest) requestContext;
            cr.bufferEntity();
            Form form = cr.readEntity(Form.class);
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> asMap = form.asMap();
            for (String key: asMap.keySet()) {
                if (asMap.get(key).size() > 1) {
                    throw new BadRequestException("Duplicate param: " + key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @NameBinding
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface NoDuplicateParams {
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(DuplicateFormParamsFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void sdhoul_get_400_with_dup() {
        final Form form = new Form()
                .param("param", "value1")
                .param("param", "value2");
        final Response response = target("test").request().post(Entity.form(form));
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(400));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void sdhoul_get_200_with_single() {
        final Form form = new Form()
                .param("param", "value1");
        final Response response = target("test").request().post(Entity.form(form));
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), is("value1"));
    }
}
```

The example used [Name Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9988), so that only methods annotated with `@NoDuplicateParams` will go through the filter. Or you can forget the name binding, and let all requests go through the filter, and just check the Content-Type in the filter for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This way you don't need to annotate everywhere.

---

### UPDATE

One thing I should mention is that I think I remember a case where this would not work (trying the extract the form as done above). I forgot exactly the case, but it had to do with a servlet environment, and the form params being read prior, so the attempted read above won't work.

What I had to do was use a Jersey internal property, where [Jersey stores the parameters](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.23.1/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L689). So you would need to retrieve the form this way

```
Form form = (Form) requestContext.getProperty(
        InternalServerProperties.FORM_DECODED_PROPERTY);
```